# AppLinkEntry AppLink Error Object reference not set in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a problem with AppLink Xamarin Android need help from everyone. Here's how I set it up:

1. Here is an example of my product detail page link: `https://domain.xxxxx/title-product-c5.html`

Link rewrite: `<rewrite url="^~/(.*)-c([0-9]+).html" to="~/detail-product.aspx?prd=$2&amp;name=$1" processing="stop"/>`

---> Everything works fine on the web

2. MainActivity.cs

   ```
   [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.ActionView,
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    },
    DataScheme = "http",
    DataHost = "domain.com",
    DataPathPrefix = "/",
    AutoVerify = true),
   ]
   [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.ActionView,
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "domain.com",
    DataPathPrefix = "/",
    AutoVerify = true),
   ]

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      ..
      FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
      AndroidAppLinks.Init(this);
      ..
    }
   ```
3. App.cs

   ```
   public static string AppName = "MyApp";
   IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductService();
   protected override async void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
   {
    string appDomain = "http://" + App.AppName.ToLowerInvariant() + "/";
    if (!uri.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(appDomain, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        return;

    string pageUrl = uri.ToString().Replace(appDomain, string.Empty).Trim();
    var parts = pageUrl.Split('?');
    string page = parts[0];
    string pageParameter = parts[1].Replace("prd=", string.Empty).Replace("name=", string.Empty);

    var formsPage = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(page));
    var todoItemPage = formsPage as DetailProduct;
    if (todoItemPage != null)
    {
        var todoItem = await productRepository.GetProductAsync(int.Parse(pageParameter));
        todoItemPage.BindingContext = todoItem;
        await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(formsPage as Page);
    }

    base.OnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);
   }
   ```
4. DetailProduct.xaml.cs

   ```
    public partial class DetailProduct : ContentPage
    {          
      IAppLinkEntry _appLink;
      AppLinkEntry GetAppLink(ProductInfo item)
      {
        var pageType = GetType().ToString();
        var pageLink = new AppLinkEntry
        {
            Title = item.Name,
            Description = item.ContentsSmall,
            AppLinkUri = new Uri($"http://{App.AppName}/{pageType}?name={item.CodeUrl}&prd={item.ID}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            IsLinkActive = true,
            Thumbnail = item.Images
        };

        pageLink.KeyValues.Add("contentType", "Article");
        pageLink.KeyValues.Add("appName", App.AppName);
        pageLink.KeyValues.Add("companyName", App.AppName);

        return pageLink;
      }

      protected override void OnAppearing()
      {
        _appLink = GetAppLink(BindingContext as ProductInfo);
        if (_appLink != null)
        {
            _appLink.IsLinkActive = true;
            Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(_appLink);
        }        
      }
   }
   ```

I created `assetlinks.json` file and uploaded it to .well-known folder

```
[
  {
    "relation": [ "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls" ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.xxx.xxxx",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [ "E2:92:B7:0A:1D:24:E5:D5:F2:87:A5:FA:94:1A:52:A3:F2:9B:3B:05:42:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ]
    }
  }
]
```

I check that link works.

However I get the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. at:

```
var pageLink = new AppLinkEntry
{
    Title = item.Name,
    Description = item.ContentsSmall,
    AppLinkUri = new Uri($"http://{App.AppName}/{pageType}?name={item.CodeUrl}&prd={item.ID}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
    IsLinkActive = true,
    Thumbnail = item.Images
};
```

I don't understand where my structure is wrong. Looking for solutions from everyone. Thanks

**Update**

I changed this line: `_appLink = GetAppLink(((ViewProductViewModel)BindingContext).ProductInfo as ProductInfo);` ----> I got the result

I got the AppLink when Debug: `http://myapp/App1.Views.DetailProduct?name=title-product&prd=5`

**And I try to open that link `http://myapp/DetailProduct?name=title-product&prd=5` in the browser. However, it only returns the result: This site can't be reached**

Am I doing something wrong when I get the applink's link?

Comment: which element of that statement is null?

Comment: Thanks, Looks like in OnAppearing() I should BindingContext directly to current ViewModel

Comment: I tried and got the results in the update above. However, I opened that link slowly from a file I saved on google driver. It still won't open the App. Can you watch it? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking#configuring-app-linking-in-android-60,? Deep linking : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking

Comment: Yes, I'm reading that document right now. And my handling is above, maybe lf is wrong :(